# Render nested data with React

Tags: javascript, angularjs, reactjs, iterator

I have an array like this:

```
let obj = [
    ['Banana', 'Apple'],
    ['Orange', 'Chicken'],
    ['Data', 'Beer']
];
```

I can't achieve to render each item in a list.

What I tried:

```
<List>
    {this.state.list.map((item, key)=>(
        {item.map((i, k) => (
            <ListItem primaryText={i}/>
        ))}
    ))}
</List>
```

Is there a way to iterate on nested data like mine with React?

I got an error on this line `{item.map((i, k) => (`, compiler says that it's waiting for `:` instead of `.`

With AngularJS, I can easily do this with something like:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
    <li ng-repeat="i in item">{{i}}</li>
</li>
```

So if there's something similar, it would be nice!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each of the nested lists need to live inside an element. Here's what the literal translation of that Angular code would look like:

```
<ul>
  {items.map(item => (
    <li>
      {item.map(i => (
        <li>{i}</li>
      ))}
    <li>
  ))}
</ul>
```

Although this doesn't make much sense, as `ul > li > li` is invalid nesting. You'd probably want to wrap the `item.map` call inside another `<ul>` element.

React elements (usually) expect to be passed an array of other React elements as children, but your original nested map was returning arrays instead.

Comment: Ow ok.. It wasn't said by compiler so I didn't think about this point. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Hmmm yeah ul li li was a bad example, Im using other thing for my view :)

Answer (score 3):

Flatten the list using [Array#concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) and [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator), and then iterate using a single [Array#map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map):

```js
const arr = [
    ['Banana', 'Apple'],
    ['Orange', 'Chicken'],
    ['Data', 'Beer']
];

const List = ({ list }) => (
  <ul>
    {[].concat(...list).map((item, key)=>(
        <li key={key}>{item}</li>
    ))}
  </ul>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <List list={arr} />,
  demo
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="demo"></div>
```